# gradle test error: retrolambda.oldJdk

Tags: java, gradle

How can I run test task in gradle while using java 8. I really would not like to install java < 7. Here are error logs obout my problem.

> ... BuildExceptionReporter]
>
> ... BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> ... BuildExceptionReporter]
>
> ... BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
>
> ... BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':test'.
>
> ... BuildExceptionReporter] > When running gradle with java 8, you must set the path to the old jdk, either with property retrolambda.oldJdk or environment variable     JAVA6_HOME/JAVA7_HOME
>
> ... BuildExceptionReporter]
>
> ... BuildExceptionReporter] * Try:
>
> ... BuildExceptionReporter] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Retrolambda need java jdk 6 or 7.
Set your environment variable JAVA6_HOME or JAVA7_HOME

https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda#configuration